# Download Weekly Google Trend Directly into R

Tags: r, google-trends

I am trying to download google trends data in the weekly period from 2014–01–01 until 2020–02–12. It seems that when I set the time to :

```
time=c("2014–01–01 2014–12–31",
       "2015–01–01 2015–12–31",
       "2016–01–01 2016–12–31",
       "2017–01–01 2017–12–31",
       "2018–01–01 2018–12–31",
       "2019–01–01 2019–12–31",
       "2020–01–01 2020–02–12")

trends = gtrends(keywords, gprop =channel,geo=country, time)
time_trend=trends$interest_over_time
```

R keep showing

> Error in gtrends(keywords, gprop = channel, geo = country, time) :
>   **length(time) <= 5 is not TRUE**

Not sure how to proceed with this

Comment: Try one time period at a time.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pass 7 time periods where the limit for the function is 5 or fewer.